# ActiveRecord model with variable number and order of fields as relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to create an application with a similar functionality with Google Forms, where a user can determine a template of different question types and then collect multiple responses per template. In specific, I need to create forms that have a user-determined number (and order) of free response (paragraph text field) and picture upload questions.

How would I set up this scheme in ActiveRecord? I am thinking of having a `FormResponse` model to store each response, which `has_many` models of the type `QuestionResponse` for the response to each question, with `TextResponse` and `UploadResponse` models as single table inheritance classes of `QuestionResponse`. Is there a more elegant method of storing such structure using ActiveRecord? How should I store the template, the structure of questions, in such a schema? Am I better off using the flexible document model of Mongo and embedding the question response documents inside a list inside a form response document?

Comment: If I was doing this, I would probably use the model you've proposed.  I would add a question class (and possibly subclasses) that would have details about question, validation, and answer_data_type.  You can then polymorphically associate your QuestionResponse with that class.  I think mongo would certainly work too.  Me personally, I'm more comfortable with relational DBs though.

Answer (score 0):

One of common concepts is to think about results and questionnaire separately and store all aggregated results for each respondent in a single record. You might use for this JSON data type if you are using Postgres. Alternatively single Mongo document also might work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Single Table Inheritance to accomplish this.

```
# Surveys have questions
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :survey_questions
end
class SurveyQuestion
    belongs_to :survey
    belongs_to :question, polymorphic: true
    acts_as_list # This is where you order your questions
end

# Questions are independent, and can be used
# in multiple Surveys
class UploadQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class TextQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base; end

# User responses are associated with the specific
# question as it appears in a Survey. Response
# table rows don't need extraneous columns.
class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class TextResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :survey_question
end
class UploadResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :survey_question
end
```

Comment: Is the benefit of this method over STI that we can save the complexity of the database table columns and that we can easily extend more Question types, at the cost of more complex model logic in the SurveyQuestion model?